# How deserialize array in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, deserialization

I'd like to deserialize array to class in Symfony but I can't find a way to do it without using e.g json or XML.

This is class:

```
class Product
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    ...
    public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
    }
    ...

}
```

Array that I'd like to deserialize to Product class.

```
$product['id'] = 1;
$product['name'] = "Test";
...
```

Comment: Take a look at the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: Of course I read it but there is no such thing like ArrayEncoder. So I can't find simple way to do this.

Comment: On the first schema http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/serializer_workflow.png we see we can use normalizer to transform object to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it through reflection like this..

```
function unserialzeArray($className, array $data)
{
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($className);
    $object = $reflectionClass->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

    foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
        if (!$reflectionClass->hasProperty($property)) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf(
                'Class "%s" does not have property "%s"',
                $className,
                $property
            ));
        }

        $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty($property);
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $reflectionProperty->setValue($object, $value);
    }

    return $object;
}
```

Which you would then call like..

```
$product = unserializeArray(Product::class, array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use denormalizer directly.

Version:

```
class Version
{
    /**
     * Version string.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $version = '0.1.0';

    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Version;

$serializer = new Serializer(array(new ObjectNormalizer()));
$obj2 = $serializer->denormalize(
    array('version' => '3.0'),
    'Version',
    null
);

dump($obj2);die;
```

result:

```
Version {#795 ▼
  #version: "3.0"
}
```